# Is there a single word for 'without a beginning'?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word for: *something that has no beginning* or *without a beginning*

Comment: Assuming you wish to exclude non-existent: most things that are considered not to have a beginning are probably also considered not to have an end either (but this is largely philosophy or dogma). Hence 'eternal' etc work.

Comment: Beginingless is a good one. In the answer below I also saw unbegun that one also seems ok.

Comment: 'Unbegun' means 'still waiting for someone to start it'. 'The dam is unbegun' and 'The dam is as yet unbegun' both mean there isn't a dam.

Comment: Schubert wrote an "Unfinished Symphony", which has two movements instead of the usual four.  P.D.Q. Bach also wrote a two-movement symphony (with movements 3 and 4 only) that is known as his "Unbegun Symphony".

Comment: @Bdy Can I ask what you are trying to describe in this way. Is it something which is known now, but hasn't started, it just is? Is it something which hasn't started, so it isn't a thing?

Comment: "minus-infinite"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

***beginningless***

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/beginningless)

> having no beginning

Comment: In spite of the word being uncommon, [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/beginningless) gives two senses for 'beginningless', the second of which is the one you mean.

Comment: Shouldn't that be "eginningless"?

Comment: @HotLicks- I found it amusing that Collins shows the Trends for 'beginningless' and the default scope is "Since Exist"

Answer (score 13):

Good question.  In traditional English theology, the closest concept is **eternal**, which also implies endlessness.  **Atemporal** implies not existing in time at all.  **Ageless** or **timeless** can literally mean having no age, but more often imply not showing the effects of time.  Words such as **primordial** traditionally carry the implication of first-created, but in a context that implies anything is eternally ancient, it would mean that instead.  I would suggest that **immemorial** comes closest.

Comment: Some sources will give you a very specific date for time immemorial: 1189-07-06. So it does not necessarily imply without a beginning.

Comment: @kasperd The literal definition is “beyond remembering,” but many words have more than one meaning. For certain purposes in English law, I suppose that is the earliest date for which records were kept, but even then, it means, older than that, not that exact date.

Comment: These are a couple of sources which will give you a specific date for time immemorial: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_immemorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vzJ9_6kDrQE

Comment: @kasperd Even in that context, “time immemorial” does not have a beginning and that is not the date of “time immemorial” itself. That’s the earliest date for which complete-enough records are extant, and “since time immemorial” means older than that.

Comment: Still it doesn't imply without beginning just that nobody remembers when it began.

Answer (score 9):

Consider the term [**unbegotten**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/unbegotten):

> not created; having no beginning; eternal

But this is a word that you're most likely to encounter only in theology. It literally means *not brought into existence by the process of sexual reproduction*.

Another good word from theology that I can recommend would be [**uncaused**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/uncaused):

> not brought into existence by any cause

In the Muslim and Christian religions as well as in Judaism, God is regarded as the uncaused cause of everything that exists. That is, God is the cause of absolutely everything, but he himself was never created which implies that he has no beginning.

Answer (score 4):

Well, 'beginningless' is an obvious phrasing but, given that **such a thing doesn't exist** outside of thought experiments, it's worth mentioning that the standard philosophical term of art for what you're discussing is the

> ## [prime mover](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/151305), *n.*
>
> **1.** A person who instigates or originates something; *spec.* G-d regarded as the motive force of the universe...

It and '**[first mover](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/123034#eid35820462)**' are calques of the Latin phrase '**primum mobile**' &c. ([which is also used in English](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/151397)), translating Arabic *al-muḥarrik al-awwal* or امحرك الأوّل (which isn't), translating Aristotle's Greek τὸ πρῶτον κινῆσαν (*tò prôton kinêsan*).

Following Aristotlean logic, some form of **[self-existent](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/175241)**, **[uncreated](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/211022)** G-d was assumed to have been necessary to get the rest of creation moving in order to avoid an infinite regress of causation. [As Davislor already mentioned](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/452803/171986), such a G-d was less eternal than **atemporal**. If there was any cause for our universe before the Big Bang, it would likewise exist outside the time known within our universe [which modern physics suggests came into existence with space](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/185429).

Answer (score 3):

'Eternal' fits the bill but isn’t as poetic as ‘anadi' or 'anaadi’, Hindi for 'without beginning, without end'.

Comment: It can't be **eternal**. Even though something may not have a beginning, it's still possible that it has an end . . .

Comment: There’s a Hebrew hymn that uses the phrase, “*B'li reshit, b'li tachlit,” but when an Israeli friend of the family came to my brother’s bar mitzvah, he couldn’t help laughing afterwards. In modern Hebrew, that still means, “Without a beginning, without an end,” but the connotation is “without a purpose”  (And is closely related to the word for end as a body part—but Exodus 33:23 reveals that.)

Comment: @Jason Bassford: It's likewise possible for something to be eternal if it has a beginning, but no end.  (In the sense that the set of positive integers is infinite.)  E.g. "eternal youth", or "eternal life" in Christian theology (as far as I understand it, anyway).

Comment: @jamesqf Yes, and I mispoke. Something without a beginning *may* be eternal, but not necessarily (depending on how you look at it). And vice-versa.

Comment: @JasonBassford `something may not have a beginning, it's still possible that it has an end` Are you sure? Can you name even one such thing?

Comment: @Will I can't definitively or objectively point to *anything* that either had no beginning or will have no end. So, this is all theoretical. But in a fantasy novel, I could point to some being that has always existed but who can still be killed in some way . . .

Comment: I don't know why you think a Hindi word with an *a-* prefix would be any more 'poetic'. It's more **pedestrian** for Indoeuropean words to just throw *a-* or *un-* in front of an adjective. You also seem to be wrong. The Hindi/Sanskrit synonym for 'eternal' seems to be [नित्य](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF) (*nitya*).

Answer (score 3):

Sourceless? I would say that in the literal meaning it would imply that the object had no source, but may possibly have an end?

Answer (score 2):

**steady-state**

While in most situations I'd go with the already-suggested **eternal**, in the very specific case where your question covers the entire universe, you could fall back to the old theory, no longer accepted, of a **steady-state** universe.

To vastly oversimplify, under the steady-state hypothesis the universe has always existed in much the same condition it has now, **with no beginning**; evidence of expansion is due to matter coming into existence from random fluctuations in, more or less, nothingness.

You can read more at Wikipedia: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steady_State_theory

Even if you are not talking about the entire universe, a steady-state equilibrium where certain conditions are unchanging over a long period of time may be sufficient for your purposes.

[Merriam-Webster defines it as:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/steady%20state)

> a state or condition of a system or process (such as one of the energy states of an atom) that does not change in time; broadly: a condition that changes only negligibly over a specified time

Answer (score 0):

You could consider unstarted and synonyms unbegun (I am sure I never said that) or uncommenced.
The world of mathematics and geometry offer the torus or Möbius strip as objects which cannot be described as having a beginning.

Comment: These default to 'yet to be started'.

Comment: In mathematics, I think I would call those “unbounded.”

Answer (score 0):

"de novo" - often used in genomics, its roots are in Latin meaning "from nothing"

Comment: Actually, **de novo** literally means "from new" and not "from nothing". It would be the phrase **ex nihilo** that means "from nothing".

Answer (score 0):

Headless - Used in IT sciences

Comment: And for decapitated chickens too.

Comment: Be careful, though: the term "headless" is also used to refer to a workstation without a monitor, intended to be used only via the network. (This usage is no longer common as cloud computing and other forms of virtualization become more prevalent.)